# Replay(1) returning result from disconnected source

Tags: system.reactive

I have an Observable stream (representing a network connection of data values) which I'm Replaying and RefCounting. The underlying source is disconnecting as expected when the subscriber count hits zero, but Replay(1) returns a value from this source to the next subscriber, which I consider to be stale. I've fixed this with a custom implementation of ReplaySubject, which forgets the last value when the last observer disconnects, but it's a leaky abstraction and I'm wondering whether there's a more idomatic way to solve this problem?

Example failing test:

```
[Test]
public async Task Replay_DoesNotReplay_AfterRefCountDisconnection()
{
    int i = 0;

    var replay = Observable.Defer(
            () =>
            {
                i++;
                return new[] {i, i}.ToObservable();
            })
        .Replay(1)
        .RefCount();

    var first = await replay.Take(1).ToTask();
    var second = await replay.Take(1).ToTask();

    Assert.AreEqual(1, first);
    Assert.AreEqual(2, second);
}
```

Comment: Can you add your custom ReplaySubject implementation to the question please?